# boxes around parts of equations

Tags: equations, box, underbrace, overbrace

I am looking for a way to draw a box around a part of an equation.
Ideally this would be something similar to `\underbrace{}_{}` or `\overbrace{}^{}` but instead of only a single bracket it's like a small box with a descriptive text. It would also be nice if the boxes can be stacked, just like in the image below.

[image]

I know this can be done, I am just struggling to find the explicit command.

***Edit:***

I wanted to add that the solution from @campa also works in connection with `\underbraces` and `\overbraces`, which looks really good.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not difficult to write something which behaves as `\overbrace`/`\underbrace` but it will have the same drawbacks: you need extra braces to get the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for \abs
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}

\newcommand*{\descbox}[1]{%
   \mathop{\boxed{#1}}\limits
}

\begin{document}

Without extra braces:
\[
\frac{d\phi}{dt}
= - R_{\mathit{wdg}} \descbox{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\phi}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}}_{i_L(\phi)}
  - R_{\mathit{wdg}}
    \descbox{
     \frac{\descbox{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}\alpha}^{k(\alpha)}\dot\alpha}% num
          {\dot\phi}%den
    }_{i_E(\phi,\dot\phi)}
  +u(t)
\]
With extra braces:
\[
\frac{d\phi}{dt}
= - R_{\mathit{wdg}} {\descbox{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\phi}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}}_{i_L(\phi)}}
  - R_{\mathit{wdg}}
    {\descbox{
     \frac{\descbox{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}\alpha}^{k(\alpha)}\dot\alpha}% num
          {\dot\phi}%den
    }_{i_E(\phi,\dot\phi)}}
  +u(t)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, since I guess you will always use this description box *with* a description I'd rather define a macro taking two arguments. The code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for \abs
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{|}{|}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\descbox}{\@ifstar{\let\@tempa\sp\desc@box}{\let\@tempa\sb\desc@box}}
\newcommand*{\desc@box}[2]{%
   {\mathop{\boxed{#2}}\limits\@tempa{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{d\phi}{dt}
= - R_{\mathit{wdg}} \descbox{i_L(\phi)}{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\phi}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}}
  - R_{\mathit{wdg}}
    \descbox{i_E(\phi,\dot\phi)}{
     \frac{\descbox*{k(\alpha)}{\frac{1+\abs{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}^S}{L_u}\alpha}\dot\alpha}% num
          {\dot\phi}%den
    }
  +u(t)
\]

\end{document}
```

gives the same result as the second formula in the preceding snapshot. I've defined `\descbox` to put the "label" (first argument) under the box by default, while the starred version puts it on top. You can reverse the behaviour by swapping the arguments of `\@ufstar`, i.e. defining

```
\newcommand*{\descbox}{\@ifstar{\let\@tempa\sb\desc@box}{\let\@tempa\sp\desc@box}}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this is a perfect answer. However, I don't quite see the difference between the first and the second screenshot? Could you please explain that again?

Comment: @Isotope Looks e.g. at the spacing around the `+` in the last term `+ u(t)`. Or around the minus sign between the two boxes.

Comment: Oh I see it now, but that is very subtle. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 Very cool use for math. Didn't think that is possible without tikz.